# Convert array of values into array of objects with that value as a property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have an array like so `[0, 1, 2, 3]`.

I want a function that converts this into `[{num: 0}, {num: 1}, {num: 2}, {num: 3}]` (using the array values as the value for a specific key). How can I do that cleanly without a for loop?

Comment: `arr.map(num => ({num}));`

Comment: Ok maybe my example is a bit extreme. Btw you can use the `map` operator

Comment: @CristianTraìna i think your example is beautiful

Comment: @lfaruki thank you. I sometimes just have fun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```js
var array1 = [0, 1, 2, 3];
var array2 = array1.map(function(ele) { return {'num':ele};});
console.log(array2);
```

**Results :**

```
[[object Object] {
  num: 0
}, [object Object] {
  num: 1
}, [object Object] {
  num: 2
}, [object Object] {
  num: 3
}]
```

[Working Demo online.](https://jsbin.com/cutesom/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the `map` operator as follows -

```js
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3];
// mapping each entry of list to a key:value pair using map()
arr = arr.map(el => {
  return {
    'num': el
  }
});
// you can use normal function() instead of arrow functions if you using ES5
/*
arr = arr.map(function(el) {
  return {
    num: el
  }
});
*/

console.log(arr);
```

You can read more about `map()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Hope this helps !

Answer (score -1):

you can try this using `map()` operator -

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3];

var newArr = arr.map(num => ({num}));

console.log(newArr);
```